How to have 3 columns height the same with overflow in tailwind
I would like to have 3 columns with the same height in tailwind.
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|                    |                                         |                    |
|                    |                                         | SCROLLABLE CONTENT |
| SCROLLABLE CONTENT | THIS DICTATES THE HEIGHT OF THE COLUMNS |                    |
|                    |                                         | -------------------|
|                    |                                         |        INPUT       |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Basically the column in the middle will dictate the height of all the other columns (which will be an aspect ratio of video size - 16:8).
I have tried:
<div class="grid grid-cols-12">
  <div class="col-span-2 flex flex-col gap-2 overflow-y-auto border border-indigo-500">
    <div>Character X</div>
    <div>Character X</div>
    <div>Character X</div>
    <div>Character X</div>
    <div>Character X</div>
    <div>Character X</div>
    <div>Character X</div>
    <div>Character X</div>
    <div>Character X</div>
    <div>Character X</div>
    <div>Character X</div>
    <div>Character X</div>
    <div>Character X</div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-span-8 aspect-video max-h-max">THIS DICTATES THE HEIGHT OF THE COLUMNS</div>
  <div class="col-span-2 overflow-y-auto">
    <div class="h-20 bg-gray-200">
      This is a message
    </div>
    <div class="h-20 bg-gray-200">
      This is a message
    </div>
    <div class="h-20 bg-gray-200">
      This is a message
    </div>
    <div class="h-20 bg-gray-200">
      This is a message
    </div>
    <div class="h-20 bg-gray-200">
      This is a message
    </div>
    <div class="h-20 bg-gray-200">
      This is a message
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


The THIS DICTATES THE HEIGHT OF THE COLUMNS div should dictate the height of the two adjacent columns:

How can I get the middle column to dictate the height of the other two columns AND make SCROLLABLE CONTENT on the right column to take as much space as possible alongside input?

The question was closed without providing another question that answers this. I have asked a different question than the linked one. The linked on doesn't divide the third column into two more sections (scrollable content and a bottom input). Could we reopen this?

Why do you not clarify that you want to "divide the third column into two more sections" until the comment? That should be more clear within the question.

You can achieve this by without grid, using relative and absolute positioning
<div class="relative w-full">
  <div class="absolute bottom-0 left-0 top-0 col-span-2 flex w-1/6 flex-col gap-2 overflow-y-auto border border-indigo-500">
    <div>Character X</div>
    <div>Character X</div>
    <div>Character X</div>
    <div>Character X</div>
    <div>Character X</div>
    <div>Character X</div>
    <div>Character X</div>
    <div>Character X</div>
    <div>Character X</div>
    <div>Character X</div>
    <div>Character X</div>
    <div>Character X</div>
    <div>Character X</div>
  </div>
  <div class="mx-auto aspect-video w-2/3">THIS DICTATES THE HEIGHT OF THE COLUMNS</div>
  <div class="absolute bottom-0 right-0 top-0 col-span-2 flex w-1/6 flex-col overflow-hidden">
    <div class="flex-1 overflow-y-auto">
      <div class="h-20 bg-gray-200">This is a message</div>
      <div class="h-20 bg-gray-200">This is a message</div>
      <div class="h-20 bg-gray-200">This is a message</div>
      <div class="h-20 bg-gray-200">This is a message</div>
      <div class="h-20 bg-gray-200">This is a message</div>
      <div class="h-20 bg-gray-200">This is a message</div>
    </div>

    <input type="text" class="border border-indigo-500" />
  </div>
</div>

view here
hope this answers your question!
